# Which is the best way to compare two xml's where the data inside them is reordered?

Tags: xml, comparison

I have two xmls where the data inside them is reordered and i want to compare them . Can anyone suggest any tool available ?

Comment: What exactly does "reordered" mean? Items that are on the same level of nesting may have switched position?

Comment: I had the similar requirement and couldn't find any tool that can do the same so I end up writing my own custom comparer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free XML Compare Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713406/free-xml-compare-tool)

Comment: @TimPietzcker : Exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the data inside is different order and you want to compare the files but disregard the order differences..

One options is to run an XSL transformation on both XML files to reorder the nodes based on a sub node. Then run the comparison on the results of the transformation.

You can use the `xsl:sort` function to do the reordering:

An example of which can be found here: [xsl:sort with apply-templates not sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824703/xslsort-with-apply-templates-not-sorting)

Comment: i have different kind of xmls. Around 900 xmls :(

Comment: 900 completely different xml structures?

Comment: around 10 types . i want to automate .

Comment: Then you can use this approach, you can set up an xslt that can handle the ten different types or have one xslt per type. Its quite manageable.
You will obviously need to set up some process that executes this automatically, but it will work.

Comment: It is copying the namespace present in the root node . How to avoid it ?

Comment: I would suggest raise a new question with specific details for this new issue. Would need more information to solve it