# Is it possible to sort using XSLT template recursive loops?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an assignment to make a table using data for a car's make, model, color, and a description. I am then asked to make a recursive loop using templates, in order to sort by the make, which is `car_rental/car/manufacturer_brand/text()`, in ascending order. Here's a version without sorting and templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
           <body>
               <table border="1">
                   <tr bgcolor="#FF5E6D">
                       <th>Car Make</th>
                       <th>Model</th>
                       <th>Color</th>
                       <th>Description</th>
                   </tr>
                   <xsl:for-each select="car_rental/car">
                       <tr>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/text()"/></td>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/model"/></td>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="main_characteristics/extra_car_info/@color"/></td>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/mini_model_description"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </table>
           </body>
       </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

They haven't given us any clues on how to sort using templates, which has made things worse. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: This is one of those infuriating questions that says "Using X, do Y", when it's much easier to do Y without using X. That's why good exam questions often cover themselves by saying "Using X, or otherwise, do Y".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824703/xslsort-with-apply-templates-not-sorting). Here is my final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#FF5E6D">
                        <th>Car Make</th>
                        <th>Model</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="car_rental/car">
                            <xsl:sort select="manufacturer_brand/text()"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="car">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/text()"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/model"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="main_characteristics/extra_car_info/@color"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="manufacturer_brand/mini_model_description"/></td><br/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your stylesheet?

Comment: Only in the sense that `xsl:apply-templates` is implicitly recursive, but certainly, I wouldn't think of this stylesheet as recursive, nor would I consider using recursion to achieve a sort.